# What's the idiomatic way to sync transitions so that adjacent shapes move together?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

Say I have an arbitrary path like this:

```
[##########]
```

I also have a circle like this: `o`

I want to keep `o` at the tip of the arbitrary path, so it looks like this:

```
[##########]o
```

(Assume `o` is centered vertically between the top and bottom of the path object) And when the path grows or shrinks, the `o` should always stay at the tip.

```
[###############]o
```

Most importantly, when a transform is applied to the path, the transform should also be applied accordingly to the circle -- they should be in sync when in motion.

I've tried making the circle a path marker, but run into trouble

- (a) getting it to only move through the center of the path
- (b) getting it to "stick" in the final position 
       
         (all examples have it infinitely rotating around the path, like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/cloudshapes/5662135) and [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1313857) and [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling two transition functions (one for each set of shapes) one after another is usually sufficient, because the time it takes the browser to run through the code is much less than the delay between animation frames.

---

However, if your animation is sufficiently complex that there is a noticeable lag between the two, or if you are doing a lot of complex calculations that will affect both elements, you could use a custom tween function on one selection, and within it select the other shape and update it (you'll want to select it in your "outer" function, so that your inner function which gets called at every update can just quickly reposition it to match the new value).

Regarding transformations, the easiest way to keep things coordinated is to put both elements in a `<g>` and transform the group instead of the individual elements.

Putting the ideas together, you could get a transition process something like this:

```
d3.selectAll("g.groups").transition().delay(time)
  .attr("transform", function(d,i){ /* Calculate new transform */ })
  .tween("stretch", function(d,i){
      /* Select the sub-elements, do all the calculations
         then create interpolators for both objects */

      var g    = d3.select(this);
      var path = g.select("path");
      var dot  = g.select("circle");

      var newEndPoint = /*** Calculate final position ***/;
      var offset = /*** distance from end point to center of circle ***/;


      var pathInterpolator = d3.interpolateString(
                 path.attr(d), 
                 /*** new path including new end point ***/
          );
      var dotInterpolator = d3.interpolateObject( 
                 {cx=dot.attr("cx"), cy=dot.attr("cy")},
                 {cx=newEndPoint.x + offset, cy=newEndPoint.y}
          );

      return function(t){
          /* the function that updates both objects at each tick */
          path.attr("d", pathInterpolator(t) );
          dot.attr( dotInterpolator(t) );
      };

  });
```

How complex your real calculations are will depend on how arbitrary your "arbitrary path" is, of course.  Maybe you'll need to calculate both x and y offsets to keep the circle positioned correctly.  But that becomes an issue of geometry, not of synchronization.  Regardless of what else your path shape does as it transitions, if the end point is an actual point in the path data, it will transition in a direct line, the same as the transition of the circle's coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up updating my marker from within the path's tween function.